# Opening a Steam Game via Pydev (Eclipse)

Tags: python, pydev, steam

I am attempting to write a program (Pydev for Eclipse) that opens a game installed with Steam (For Honor), clicks around and does a few things, and exits. I tested the possibility of doing each step by replacing the game with MS Word, and it worked perfectly! I thought all I had to do was replace the path for Word with the path for the game, but it did not work. I got an error message that says "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied".

Here is the statement that I used to open Word (and what I tried to use to open the game)

```
dv = subprocess.Popen(['C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE'])
```

Is there an extra step I have to take?

**EDIT:** I figured out the issue. Part of the path was not included in the statement. I have since been able to do what I intended.

Thank you for the help **:)**

Comment: You're trying to launch a process to which the user running the script doesn't have permissions. Either run your script as Administrator (or user who has the permissions to run whatever you're trying to run) or change permissions of your process (and all files and directories it 'touches') to include the user running the script.

Comment: How would I run the script as administrator from Eclipse?

Comment: Run Eclipse as Administrator, every process it runs will then be running in the same permissions space.

Comment: I tried that as well... It didn't work. I got the same error message as before.